# mapboxmap location text is reversed in arabic text

Tags: android, mapbox

look at the image below :
[image]

as you see the text in arabic is appearing revered and user can not read it.
i searched api for methods like *setTimezone*,*setLocale* , etc but couldn't find anything.
is there any way to fix this ? 
EDIT : 
this is a bug in [mapbox android sdk](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl/issues/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, you can read more about it and track the progress in [this Github issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl/issues/4).